# Vectorize addition of multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe:

```
   val1  val2  val3  val4  total
0     1     2     3     4     50
1     5     6     4     8     65
2     2     3     6     5     74
```

And I would like to create some new columns based on simple addition and division of columns. I will be getting a proportion/ratio each time so I set up a quick function to do this:

```
def vectorize(df,value_cols,total_col):

    return df[value_cols] / df[total_col]
```

Now I would like to get the proportion of `val1` in relation to `total`:

```
total = 'total'
values = 'val1'

df['result'] = vectorize(df,values,total)

   val1  val2  val3  val4  total    result
0     1     2     3     4     50  0.020000
1     5     6     4     8     65  0.076923
2     2     3     6     5     74  0.027027
```

That looks great.

Now when I want to add multiple columns before dividing by `total`, I run into problems.

For example, I try to find the proportion of `val1 + val2` in relation to `total`:

```
total = 'total'
values = ['val1','val2']

df['result2'] = vectorize(df,values,total)

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1
```

This doesn't work, because my column names are now in a list. It's returning a dataframe of `Nans`.

Is there an easy way around this?

I tried adding `sum()` to the function, but I'm not getting the correct results:

```
return df[value_cols].sum() / df[total_col]
```

I tried using `enumerate` to add columns together before dividing by `total`:

```
for i,col in enumerate(value_cols):

    sums = df[col] += df[col]

    return sums / df[total_col]
```

But none of this is working.

I am basically trying to automate this in the function:

```
df['val1'] + df['val2'] / df['total']
```

But also allow for single columns i.e. just `val1` alone.

My real world dataframe has hundreds of columns and I would like to to add one or multiple columns together like this. I could type it all out by hand, but I wanted to try speed it up by creating a vectorizing function.

My df for reproducability:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({'val1': pd.Series([1, 5, 2],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)), 'val2': pd.Series([2, 6, 3],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)), 'val3': pd.Series([3, 4, 6],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)), 'val4': pd.Series([4, 8, 5],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)), 'total': pd.Series([50, 65, 74],dtype='int64',index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1))}, index=pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1))
```

Comment: it's actually far from necessary. just pass a list when you have only one column so you can use it for multiple columns too. i can think of plenty of libraries that ask for a list even for one value. `callbacks` and `metrics` arguments of keras come to mind.

Comment: But in the dataframe I am working with, there are 700 `val` columns. This is all census data, such as `number of employed / total population`, `number of females / total population`, `number of single + number of separated + number of divorced / total population` etc etc. I would rather not have to write `val_x` + `val_y` / total` over and over again.

Comment: You need to create all of the sums and totals yourself because there is no pattern to the column names that you need to sum. Then just `df[list_of_all_numer_cols].divide(df['total'], axis=0)` in a single line. Personally, if you want to create a function for anything, it should be for the many sums you need to perform, not the single one-line vectorized division you can do in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do:

```
def vectorize(df,value_cols,total_col):
    # for multiple columns
    if isinstance(value_cols, list):
        return df[value_cols].sum(axis=1) / df[total_col]
    # for single column
    return df[value_cols] / df[total_col]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tweak your function:

```py
def vectorize(df,value_cols,total_col):
    if(isinstance(value_cols, list)):
        return df[value_cols].apply(sum, axis=1).div(df[total_col])
    else:
        return df[value_cols].div(df[total_col])
```

Output:

```py
   val1  val2  val3  val4  total    result   result2
0     1     2     3     4     50  0.020000  0.060000
1     5     6     4     8     65  0.076923  0.169231
2     2     3     6     5     74  0.027027  0.067568
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.sum()` was the right thing to do. But you need to specify the axis along which you want to add. By default it adds the rows, not the columns. This is what you need:

```
return df[value_cols].sum(axis=1) / df[total_col]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to perform many divisions, with the possibility of summing columns prior, I would slightly modify the function. Pass it a `DataFrame`, your denominator column, and then a list of lists that specifies which columns to add based on each sublist.

```
def sum_then_divide(df, total_col, numer_col_list):
    """
    df : pd.DataFrame
    total_col : str, denominator
    numer_col_list: list of lists
        Sum all columns in each sublist before dividing
    """
    u = pd.concat([df[cols].sum(1).rename('+'.join(cols)) for cols in numer_col_list], axis=1)
    return u.divide(df[total_col], axis=0)

sum_then_divide(df, 'total', [['val1'], ['val1', 'val2'], ['val1', 'val3', 'val4']])
#       val1  val1+val2  val1+val3+val4
#0  0.020000   0.060000        0.160000
#1  0.076923   0.169231        0.261538
#2  0.027027   0.067568        0.175676
```